# Editing an xlsx document whilst preserving a chart

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, charts

I have an Excel template that I would like to ultimately serve as the output of my python script with data from the script dumped onto certain tabs, and formatted. Typically I would use either `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter` to open or create this output, however I have an area chart within the report that I would like to preserve, and neither of these modules allow for charts to be read.

Is there a way around this with another module? If I use `win32api`, does the computer that I run the script on need to have Excel installed (I'd like it to be scheduled on an EC2 instance once complete)?